# Reversing an integer using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

While practicing recursion I came across a question to reverse an integer using recursion. I tried to do the question without converting the integer into a string.

I was able to solve the question partially but the output would always come without any of the zeroes from the original input. Below is the code I came up with:

```
def reverseNumber(n):
    if (n//10) == 0:
        return n
    lastDigit = n%10
    ans = reverseNumber(n//10)
    nod = 0
    for i in str(ans):
        nod += 1
    return (10**nod)*lastDigit + ans
```

Upon inspection I could see that this was happening because when `lastDigit` is 0 it only returned the reversed integer from the recursive call i.e input 4230 will give 324.

But this also meant that all zeroes between the original input would also get removed as we went deeper in the recursive calls.

So please tell me how to modify this code so that zeroes in the original input are not removed while reversing.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need just this:

```
def rev(n):
    if n>0:
        return str(n%10)+rev(n//10)
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`reverseNumber` should return an `int` and accept positive and negative numbers.

The simplest way to fix your code, without handling negative numbers, is:

```
def reverseNumber(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    lastDigit = n%10
    n //= 10
    return int(str(lastDigit) + str(reverseNumber(n))) if n else lastDigit

for test in (0, 123, 120):
    print(test, reverseNumber(test))
```

Prints:

```
0 0
123 321
120 21
```

Yes! The reverse of 120 is 21 when you are dealing with `int` types as opposed to `str` types.

Another implementation that does handle negative numbers takes a whole different approach:

I have broken this out into two functions. Function `rev` is a generator function that assumes that it is being called with a positive, non-negative number and will recursively yield successive digits of the number in reverse. `reverseNumber` will join these numbers, convert to an `int`, adjust the sign and return the final result.

```
def reverseNumber(n):

    def rev(n):
        assert n >= 0
        yield str(n % 10)
        n //= 10
        if n != 0:
            yield from rev(n)

    if n == 0: return 0 # special case
    x = int(''.join(rev(abs(n))))
    return x if n >= 0 else -x

tests = [0, 132, -132, 120]
for test in tests:
    print(test, reverseNumber(test))
```

Prints:

```
0 0
132 231
-132 -231
120 21
```

Answer (score 0):

For all non-negative `n`, when `n < 10` it is a single digit and already the same as its reverse -

```
def reverse(n = 0):
  if n < 10:
    return str(n)
  else
    return str(n%10) + rev(n//10)
```

Comment: The rev() function in last line looks familiar :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the following Python3 code. It will cover positive and negative integers to be reversed as integers - not as strings ...

```
x = int(input("What integer shall be reversed? "))

n = abs(x)                          # ... to handle negative integers
r = 0                               # ... will hold the reversed int.

while n > 0:                        # Recursion part reversing int.
    r = (r * 10) + (n % 10)         # using '%' modulo
    n = int(n / 10)                 # and a 'dirty way' to floor

if x < 0:                           # Turn result neg. if x was neg. 
    return (r * -1)
else:
    return r                        # Keep result pos. if x was pos.
```

This approach will leave your zeros in the middle of the integer intact, though it will make any zero at the end of the initial number vanish - rightfully so as integers do not start with a zero. ;))